# Webview gets rendered first while rest of activity is black

Tags: android, android-webview

Having quite a strange problem with WebView, decided to ask seasoned Android guys who might have come across similar behavior. The scenario goes as follows:

- Opening an activity which has a bunch of textViews in it and single WebView. Rendering everything is just fine initially.
- From this activity opening another activity which shows some additional details related to the first activity.
- When user clicks 'Back' button and the Details activity gets closed I expect the main activity to render itself back properly, but in 50% of cases the WebView is shown immediately while the rest of activity is black for about a second. Quite annoying.

I fill in the activity controls with following code:

```
void fillData(Context context){     

    Command cmd = cmdList.get(index);

    if(cmd.getTypeId() == CMD_TYPE_EXTENSION){
        cmdName.setText(cmd.getName());
        String extStr = DALHelper.getInstance().getExtensionName(Integer.toString(cmd.getExtensionId()));
        extName.setText(extStr.substring(0, extStr.length() - 1));
        cmdDesc.setText(cmd.getDescription());
    }else{
        String name=cmd.getName()
                .concat(" (")
                .concat(cmd.getDescription())
                .concat(")");
        cmdName.setText(name);
        cmdDesc.setText(cmd.getComments());
    }
    if(cmd.getSyntax() != null){
        String s = alignSyntaxText(cmd.getSyntax());            
        cmdSyntax.setText(s);
    }

    String params = DALHelper.getInstance().getHtmlParameters(Integer.toString(cmd.getId()));
    if(params.length() > 0){
        params = params.substring(DUMMY_TAG_INDEX);
        htmlParams.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://not/needed", Utils.removeBadCharacters(params), "text/html", "utf-8", null);         
    }           

    scroll.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
}
```

May the last call to fullScroll() be the reason for that?

Something else to mention is that the WebView sits inside a scrollView along with other text fields, however it wraps content so there are no double-scrolling glitches there.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was found. Was caused by double call to fillData() method mentioned above, first time while opening the Details activity and the second time in onResume() of main activity. Most likely it caused some rendering glitches, not sure what exactly though.